# Replace system call in linux kernel 3

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, kernel-module

I am interested in replacing a system call with a custom that I will implement in linux kernel 3.
I read that the sys call table is no longer exposed.

Any ideas?

any reference to this http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/linux_kernel/linux_kernel_module_programming_2.6/x978.html example but for kernel 3 will be appreciated :)

Thank you!

Comment: Is there a reason why you need to replace one, and not just add a new system call?

Comment: @Kristian, the reason is to spy out the calls going over a given syscall using a kernel module. Hopefully for debugging purposes :-)

Comment: Why can't he just modify the existing call in the source code then? They should all be available in `arch/<architecture>/kernel/`

Comment: Why is the exposure of the syscall table a problem? Are you planning to compile a new kernel, or to hijack an existing one?

Comment: @Kristian, because then you need to recompile the kernel, it's easier to just compile and insert a kernel module to activate the "feature" and rmmod it to deactivate it.

Comment: I want to log information (i.e. UID) for every user that connects successfully via ssh. So i suppose that I have to intercept the syscall of sshd that accepts the connections.

Comment: Also yes, I don't want a solution that contains the process of recompiling the kernel :)

Comment: @Panos: you don't need any extra or modified system call for that. `lsof`, `strace` are enough (both using `ptrace` system call).

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I didn't know ptrace syscall! I will investigate it now

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch `lsof` does not use the `ptrace` system call to get the file descriptors information. On Linux it uses the `/proc` interface IRC.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would recommend using kprobes for this kind of job, you can easily break on any kernel  address (or symbol...) and alter the execution path, all of this at runtime, with a kernel module if you need to :)

Kprobes work by dynamically replacing an instruction (e.g. first instruction of your syscall entry) by a break (e.g. int3 on x86). Inside the do_int3 handler, a notifier notifies kprobes, which in turn passes the execution to your registered function, from which point you can do almost anything.

A very good documentation is given in [Documentation/kprobes.txt](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kprobes.txt) so as a tiny example in [samples/kprobes/kprobes_example.c](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/samples/kprobes/kprobe_example.c) (in this example they break on do_fork to log each fork on the system). It has a very simple API and is very portable nowdays.

**Warning**: If you need to alter the execution path, make sure your kprobes are not optimized (i.e. a jmp instruction to your handler replaces the instruction you break onto instead of an int3) otherwize you won't be able to really alter the execution easily (after the ret of your function, the syscall function will still be executed as usual). If you are only interested in tracing, then this is fine and you can safely ignore this issue.

Comment: Sorry I've just read the comments on your question. Seems like you just want to know when someone login through sshd. ptrace() has been suggested but IMHO, the downside performance wise is really not worth it. If all you want to do is being notified when someone login with sshd, you'd better just use sshd logs. You could write a crontab job that read those logs and send you an email each time there is a successful/denied login. You could write all of this in a scripting language which can considerably reduce the time of dev. in your case.

Comment: Exactly! I will investigate the kprobe that you suggested and reply if it worked for my case :) Thanks!!!

Comment: I investigated jprobes and it's really amazing! My only concern is that I don't know which kernel routine is called when the accept system call accepts a socket connection :(

Comment: for tcp connections is tcp_connect! Now I just have to find the call for the new UDP connections!

Comment: I'm glad it suited your needs :) Generally for finding the syscall function inside the kernel, you just need to add  the prefix `sys_`, so for all accept (tcp and udp), you would normally break on `sys_accept`. And yeah jprobes are really nice to work with when all you want is trace! There are higher level interfaces that uses kprobes internally that you might find usefull, like with ftrace: you don't even need to write a kernel module but can use an interface in debugfs, read Documentation/trace/ftrace for more information. There is also the audit subsystem but you need to write a daemon.

Comment: Can you please have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8314291/extract-information-from-struct-socket? :)

I monitor 4 kernel functions, for incoming, outgoing TCP and UDP connection instead of monitoring the sys_connect and sys_accept (didn't find them :( )

Comment: You probably did not find them because they are wrapped in a preprocessor macro `SYSCALL_DEFINE(accept)`. I recommend you generate a TAGS file for your kernel sources so that you can look for particular symbols more easily using emacs/vim or whatever editor you are using. To generate, it's as easy as typing `make TAGS` in your kernel source directory.
For `sys_accept` it is located in `net/socket.c` line 1560 on a 3.0.3 kernel. I'll take a look at your other question this evening if nobody has answered it ;)

Comment: I found how to get the file descriptor of the socket, then the pid, then the process name and the uid! My only problem is that I need to have access to the newsock, so I need to plant a jprobe function *after* the sys_accept is called, in order to have access to the contents of newsock. Do you know how can I manage to do this?
Thank you very much!!!

Comment: description for the jprobe struct from the krpobe header

"Because of the way compilers allocate stack space for local variables
 * etc upfront, regardless of sub-scopes within a function, this mirroring
 * principle currently works only for probes placed on function entry points."

so there is no way... :(

Comment: There is always a way :) What you really need is the `kretprobe`, and not jprobe or kprobe. In the same way you can register handlers except instead of having the same prototype of the function, you receive a `struct pt_regs` as argument. Then it is your duty to look into that `struct pt_regs` to get the arguments, return value, etc... It is just an extra step that you need to do (warning this structure is obviously architecture dependent). The advantage that you get is that you can put your handler on the function return (i.e. when `accept` has filled the content of newsock). Have fun :)

Comment: My comment was too long but I just wanted to add that if you are planning on looking at this structure by yourself, you really need to understand in what context your handler will be run: it's not granted that you will be able to deref an address from the `struct pt_regs` as the address is only valid in the VM of the user process. It is usually fine on x86 as the probes are optimized by a `jmp` so you are effectively in user context. It is not always the case so if your code needs to be portable, you'll have to to a bit more work. Again if all you want is trace, take a look at ftrace.

Comment: I am disappointed. I decided to follow your idea of kprobes via a post handler, but I don't know how to recover the system call parameters from the registers :( :( I posted a question here about that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8437149/get-syscall-parameters-with-kprobes-post-handler. Any help is HIGHLY appreciated. Sorry for my insistance  :(

Answer (score 1):

Write a LKM that would be better optio.What do you mean by replace,do you want to add a new one.

Comment: I don't want to add a new one. I want to be notified when a system call is called and extract some information from it's parameters

Comment: replace and add are two fundamental and non ambiguous operations in software engineering. Do you really need asking whether replace means add? `</passive-aggressive>`