# Get syscall parameters with kretprobes post handler

Tags: architecture, linux-kernel, kernel, trace, kernel-module

I want to trace with a LKM the sys_connect and sys_accept right after these system calls return.
I found that kprobes can give you access to the registers when a probed system call returns, by defining a post handler.

My problem is that I don't know how to get the system call parameters from the data that I have in the post handler (i.e. the struct pt_regs)
The post handler is defined like that:

```
void post_handler(struct kprobe *p, struct pt_regs *regs, unsigned long flags);
```

Comment: I found [this article](http://www.phrack.org/issues.html?issue=67&id=6) very useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This structure is architecture dependent so I will just assume you are on x86.

On entry:

```
  orig_eax = syscall_nr;
  ebx = 1st argument of the function;
  ecx = 2nd arg...
  edx = 3rd arg...
  esi = 4th arg...
  edi = 5th arg... (you are lucky, on other arch this can be on the stack...)
```

On exit:

```
  orig_eax = return value of the function
```

You cannot assume that the value inside ebx,ecx,edx... still points to the argument of the function on exit (i.e. when your post_handler is called) so here you would need to register **two** handlers, one on entry, from which you can can save a pointer to the struct socket, and one on exit, from which you will actually inspect the content of the struct socket now that it's been filled. To pass data between the two handlers, you can use the filed `data` of the `kretprobe_instance` structure. Don't forget to increase the `data_size` filed of the `struct kretprobe` when you register your kretprobe.

This might seem a little complex but it should be alright once you are a bit more familiar with it.

Please also remember that if the only thing you need to do is trace those events, you might just use the ftrace infrastructure in sysfs and with minimum efforts get the trace that you want.

Comment: Can I see your code (only where it actually fails on)? It's a bit weird that you get this error at compile time as the symbol should be resolved only when you load the module (more specifically when you register your kretprobe)). If you use the field `symbol_name`, the type is `char*`, not a function pointer.

Comment: Exactly, I used the symbol_name and it compiled :)
I decided that I can extract the information that I want to log by just getting the socket fd from the accept syscall. This value is returned from sys_accept. Can I take this value from the ORIG_EAX through the post handler? If yes, how? (i.e. in the x86 arch). *Thanks* again for your help :)

Comment: Hmm I found the regs_return_value function. I print the value, but it's huge, there is no way that this is the socket fd =/

Comment: Hmm I cast the return value to an integer pointer and I print the contained int. The result is 1. Weird :S

Comment: My mistake, it wasn't on sys_accept. I tried this on sys_accept and my machine crashed... :(

Comment: Now I print the regs_return_value in sys_accept post handler and it's always 4. Why? I think this is the syscall number of accept, but it should be the socket fd :S

Comment: No it is actually the fd returned by accept, which is quite normal for an application that does nothing else. You have 0, 1 and 2 recorded for stdin, stdout and stderr. Then before doing an accept() you need a socket_fd (returned by a call to socket()) which is likely to be 3 if you haven't opened anything else. Then comes the accept, so naturally it's 4 :) If you want, create your own program which does this and open a few files before doing your socket()/accept() pair, you'll see that the value won't be 4.

Comment: Yes I knew that, my mistake was that I wasn't using the kretprobe :D It works (at last) now :D

Comment: ooo I see you were using the kprobe with a post_handler! Yep, it explains a lot :) Glad to hear that it works now